# How to sign the Certificates with Elliptic curve private keys and ECDSA algorithm?

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I am able to sign the certificates using bouncy castle with RSA private Keys and "SHA256withRSA " algorithm.  I have used below link for reference to achieve this.
[Sign CSR using Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230330/sign-csr-using-bouncy-castle)

Now I have my CAs with Elliptic Curve keys signed with ECDSA. Hence I want to sign the certificates with EC key and "SHA256withECDSA" algorithm by these CAs. 
However I am stuck at below snippet specific to RSA key, I want to use EC key.

```
ContentSigner sigGen = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(privateKeyParam);
```

Please help me how we can achieve Certificate signing with ECDSA and EC keys

Comment: Check if this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287795/java-bouncycastle-ecc-keys-and-self-signed-certificates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below code used to sign the certificates with EC private keys

```
ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withECDSA").build(new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey(PrivateKeyInfo));
```